# How can I change the Turkish characters and the space in the json data object names ? WebApi/Typescript

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, replace

I am using api fetch data. But my json data format has Turkish characters and space. Thats why I couldn't get the datas to datatable or anything. I tried replace or parse function but I have no result.

> real json format

```json
 {
        "Kod Adı": "USD",
        "Alış Kür": "12.4448"
    },
    {
        "Kod Adı": "AUD",
        "Alış Kür": "8.8412"
    },
    {
        "Kod Adı": "DKK",
        "Alış Kür": "1.8851"
    },
    {
        "Kod Adı": "EUR",
        "Alış Kür": "14.0385"
    },
    {
        "Kod Adı": "GBP",
        "Alış Kür": "16.5046"
    },
```

> format to be

```json
 {
        "KodAdi": "USD",
        "AlisKur": "12.4448"
    },
    {
        "KodAdi": "AUD",
        "AlisKur": "8.8412"
    },
    {
        "KodAdi": "DKK",
        "AlisKur": "1.8851"
    },
    {
        "KodAdi": "EUR",
        "AlisKur": "14.0385"
    },
    {
        "KodAdi": "GBP",
        "AlisKur": "16.5046"
    },
```

Also I am getting *CORS policy* error.

> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried to use this link. However, I did not get any results. [3 Ways to Fix the CORS Error](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)

> shared.service.ts

```js
getAnalizor() : Observable<any[]>{
  return this.http.get<any>('http://15.12.1.05/analizorJSON.php')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the field names to below function -

```
function decodeTurkishCharacters(text) {
  return text
    .replace(/\ğ/g, "g")
    .replace(/\ü/g, "u")
    .replace(/\ş/g, "s")
    .replace(/\ı/g, "i")
    .replace(/\ö/g, "o")
    .replace(/\ç/g, "c");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [String.prototype.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to remove the accented characters.

```js
const str = "Alış Kür"
str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
> "Alıs Kur"
```

Check out [Unicode Normalization Forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) to get to know the difference between `NFD` and `NFC`

The normalize() function with NFD decomposes accented characters into the combination of simple ones. The ü becomes u +  ̈.

Next we do a regex replace to remove the U+0300 → U+036F range with contains all the Diacritical Marks.

To support the `ı` you might still have to do another regex replacement like `replace(/\ı/g, "i")`

so finally

```js
const str = "Alış Kür"
str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").replace(/\ı/g, "i").replace(" ", "")
> "AlisKur"
```